# How to display JavaScript image with hyperlink inside a function

Tags: javascript, html

Programming and JavaScript noob here, so I appreciate all the help I can get.  I'm using CometChat on my website and having some trouble working with their API's.  I don't think it's a matter of the API's, it's more how to implement them.  I pulled these lines of code from the CometChat website and more or less cut-n-pasted them into a user's profile page (I actually have a CMS system where I can implement this code on the fly).  This bit of code goes on a user's profile page (user with ID number 160881).

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:jqcc.cometchat.chatWith('160881');"><img src="http://www.wechsupport.com/content/images/chatwithme.png" alt="Click here to chat with me now"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">

function checkstatus(data) {
    if (data.s == 'available') {
        alert('User is online');
    }
}

window.onload = function() {     jqcc.cometchat.getUser('160881','checkstatus')}; </script>
```

When navigating to the user's page, first an alert is displayed stating "User is online".  Clicking OK, the alert disappears.  Also, an image called CHATWITHME is displayed.  That's fine, it works, but it's nasty.  What I'd rather do is get rid of the alert all together and just display the CHATWITHME image/link if the user's status comes back as available (as shown in the function called CHECKSTATUS).  I was thinking to simply take the A HREF piece and replace the ALERT with it such as this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkstatus(data) {
    if (data.s == 'available') {
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:jqcc.cometchat.chatWith('160881');"><img src="http://www.wechsupport.com/content/images/chatwithme.png" alt="Click here to chat with me now"></a>;
    }
}

window.onload = function() {     jqcc.cometchat.getUser('160881','checkstatus')}; </script>
```

But this did not work.  The alert went away (which is guess is good), but the image/link is not displayed.  I have very limited experience working with code and simply don't know how to get the anchor tag to work within the function.  I can use whatever help is offered.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="chatwithmebutton"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
function checkstatus(data) {
    if (data.s == 'available') {
        document.getElementById('chatwithmebutton').innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:jqcc.cometchat.chatWith(160881);"><img src="http://www.wechsupport.com/content/images/chatwithme.png" alt="Click here to chat with me now"></a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: This will display multiple buttons if the users status changes more than 1 time.

Comment: @TheCodingMonk I don't think that jqcc.cometchat.getUser('160881','checkstatus') is registering some interval to check against users online :)

Comment: Yeah, probably not, but it would be better anyway to just show a div instead of writing to the document

Comment: Thanks for the help on that.  It kinda worked.  The button was displayed on a blank page... typical of what document.write would normally do.  Is there a way to place it inline with the rest of the page?  This script is in the middle of the page in the "user information" section.

Comment: use my edited code :) this will show up the button as expected.. did not think of the onload event :) just place the html code where your button should appear :)

Comment: TheCodingMonk, I think you're right on that.  Can you give me a quick sample of how to insert this button as a div?

Comment: (I actually misunderstood your previous comment, though. I mean, if you want to show the button when the user status comes back as available you necessarily have to register an interval anyway, so that's why I said the first solution wasn't as good as this one)

Comment: This one worked exactly as expected.  Showed the button if the user was available, showed nothing if the user was not available.  Gonna create a "User Offline" button and see if we can't get it to display that instead if the user is offline.  I think it would simply involve creating a DIV ID called "UserOnlineButton" and another called "UserOfflineButton".  In the If statement, call the UserOnlineButton.  In the else statement

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Javascript `setInterval()` function to call the `jqcc.cometchat.getUser` method every X seconds. If you want to show/hide the button every time the status changes you also have to modify your HTML a bit:

```
<div id="chat-button">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:jqcc.cometchat.chatWith('160881');"><img src="http://www.wechsupport.com/content/images/chatwithme.png" alt="Click here to chat with me now"></a>
</div>
```

And, in the `checkstatus()` function do something like:

```
function checkstatus() {
    if (data.s == 'available') {
        $('#chat-button').show();
    } else {
        $('#chat-button').hide();
    }
}
```

(I'm using jQuery syntax in the Javascript code)

Comment: Thanks for the assistance on this.  Where would I insert the div tag?

Comment: The div tag goes where the button goes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  I created an "offline" button and uploaded it.  Modified the code submitted by Walialu (thank you) slightly and came up with this:

```
<div id="chatonlinebutton"></div>
<div id="chatofflinebutton"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function checkstatus(data) {
    if (data.s == 'available') {
        document.getElementById('chatonlinebutton').innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:jqcc.cometchat.chatWith(160881);"><img src="http://www.wechsupport.com/content/images/chatwithme.png" alt="Click here to chat with me now"></a>';
    }     else {
        document.getElementById('chatofflinebutton').innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.wechsupport.com/content/images/chatoffline.png" alt="User is offline right now">';
    }
}

window.onload = function() {     jqcc.cometchat.getUser('160881','checkstatus')}; </script>
```

If the user is online, the online button is displayed.  If not, a simple graphic stating "User is offline" is displayed.

Thanks so much!!